# Android - How to serialize in JSON only the explicit fields of an extended class

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, extends

I have some classes like that:

```
class A {
    String fieldA;
    String fieldB;
}

class B extends A {
    String fieldA;
    String fieldC;
}
```

I know I can avoid to declare fieldA twice but in my case I have to.

While doing

```
JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(GsonSelector.getCurrentGson().toJson(auth, <The_Class>.class));
```

I have obviously have

```
10-28 15:24:56.645: E/AndroidRuntime(11498): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class <The_Class> declares multiple JSON fields named <Name>
```

because in the extended class the fields are declared twice.

My question is:

**How can I serialize only the fields of the extended class, ignoring the parent fields?**

Keep in mind that I have to be able to also serialize from the parent class (**A**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a viable solution:

**1** I removed the extension dependecy (With this solution I don't need it more, it's up to you)

**2** Created a "more root" class that contains only the fields that I want to share between classes and that I want to avoid.

**3** Added to these fields the following annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
public @interface JsonIgnore {

}
```

**4** Added the custom annotation we created to our exclusion strategy of the JSON serializer (deserializer)

```
public class MyExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return f.getAnnotation(JsonIgnore.class) != null;
    }

}
```

**Following the previous example, here is how it looks like:**

```
class Root {
    @JsonIgnore
    String fieldA;
}

class A extends Root {
    String fieldA;
    String fieldB;
}

class B extends Root {
    String fieldA;
    String fieldC;
}
```

The duplicate field "fieldA" will not be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear **why** you need the duplication. However, you can use a [custom deserializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) to achieve what you want. An example is available [here](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/).